# Proving that a set with a ternary logical connective is functionally incomplete (i.e. inadequate)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I am stucked at trying to prove that the set $\{\lnot ,G\}$ of logical connectives is inadequate where $G$ is a ternary connective that gives $T$ (True) if **most** of its arguments are $T$.

For example: 
$G(T,T,F)=T$ since there are more $T$'s than $F$'s 
and $G(F,F,T)=F$ since there are more $F$'s than $T$'s

It seems that we cannot express tautologies and contradictions with this set of connectives but when I tried to prove it (using structural induction) I got stucked.

Thanks for any hint or help.

Comment: How exactly are you defining functional completeness?

Comment: @Git Gud: it's a standard notion. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness.

Comment: @RobArthan I know two ways of defining functional completeness. One doesn't require reduction to standard connectives, the other does. The wikipedia link doesn't help in this respect.

Comment: @Git Hud: please elucidate. The wikipaedia link gives the standard definition of a functionally complete set of connectives as one that can define any truth-theoretic function.

Comment: I've seen similar in some boolean logic forms, with the $\text{Maj}(\vec{p_n})$ function being defined as ${\left \lfloor \frac{1}{2} +  \frac{\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n  p_i\right) - 1/2}{n} \right \rfloor}$; yours seems to be a special case where $n=3$. I'm not sure if this helps, but it's my two cents ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider just two propositional variables, say $p$ and $q$, and let's see what truth-functions of these we can express using $\neg$ and $G$.  Using just $\neg$, we have $p,q,\neg p,\neg q$. Now let's apply $G$ to any triple of these, say $G(x,y,z)$.  If two of $x,y,z$ are the same, the $G$ just produces that same one of $p,q,\neg p,\neg q$ as its output.  So the only way to get anything new would be if $x,y,z$ are distinct elements of $\{p,q,\neg p,\neg q\}$.  But then, since only one of $p,q,\neg p,\neg q$ is missing from $x,y,z$, this triple would contain either both $p$ and $\neg p$ or both $q$ and $\neg q$.  But if some two of $x,y,z$ are each other's negations, then $G(x,y,z)$ agrees with the other one of $x,y,z$, so we still get nothing new.  Conclusion: The only truth fnctions of $p$ and $q$ that can be expressed using $\neg$ and $G$ are $p,q,\neg p,\neg q$.