# How many ternary functionally complete connectives are there?

Tags: logic, reference-request, propositional-calculus

Today I was reading up once more on some of the nice results regarding [functional completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness), notably Post's celebrated classification theorem with the 5 classes that need to be avoided. (See [this PDF](https://www.sfu.ca/~jeffpell/papers/PostPellMartin.pdf) for a nice overview and proof of this result.)

Now it is well-known that the only two functionally complete binary connectives are the Sheffer strokes.

From these and the other familiar functionally complete pairs it is easy to construct some functionally complete *ternary* connectives. But not all of them will have such a nice reducible form.

---

How many ternary functionally complete connectives are there (out of $2^{2^3} = 256$ options)? Can they be easily described?

I'm also curious about the $n$-ary case, so if it can be easily generalised, go ahead -- particularly where it comes to a characterisation of these connectives.

I realise this might be a bit tough to address in complete detail in an answer, so I'm also definitely welcoming references and/or partial results.

Comment: Most probably, the answer is, no simple way.

Comment: among the n-ary operators ($n=3$ being a particular case), the majority vote operator (value 1 iff there are more ones than zeros as entries) may be  of interest...

Comment: @JeanMarie: Why is it of interest? It is not complete even with constants 0,1 because it's monotonic. However, the minority operator with constant 0 is complete. I'm sure it's also not complete if you don't have constants but I don't see an easy way to prove it right now.

Comment: @user21820 Minority is self-dual.

Comment: I just had a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1251531 ...

Comment: @JeanMarie: Ah thanks for that!

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=IwbjBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA159&lpg=PA159&dq=n-ary+scheffer+functions&source=bl&ots=3sXp0FGJzT&sig=SdLujSLh4MO5MeIzCsPEDU26Q1M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizpsy7-7TMAhXEGZAKHTnZAPgQ6AEIKDAB#v=onepage&q=n-ary%20scheffer%20functions&f=false).

Comment: @JMarcos Thanks! That answers the question for all $n$: the number is $2^{2^n-2}-2^{2^{n-1}}$. Could you distil the two-sentence analysis given there into an answer with proof (given Post's result)?

Comment: I apologize for not having the due time to detail the analysis here. The combinatorial argument may be found at a few texts on [clones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_(algebra)) (Universal Algebra), such as [this one](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=WnSWX8yYPfoC&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=sheffer+functions+n-ary&source=bl&ots=jPS1minegH&sig=-U7QLxoZbo_290ZZC6ZpLVjywx4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinxPPH57fMAhXFbB4KHcHTB3kQ6AEILzAD#v=onepage&q=enumerate%20sheffer%20functions%20n-ary&f=false) (check in particular Corollary 1.6).