# Proving a set of connectives is inadequate

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The question has already posted here before:
[Proving that a set with a ternary logical connective is functionally incomplete (i.e. inadequate)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251531/proving-that-a-set-with-a-ternary-logical-connective-is-functionally-incomplete)
But I came up with a different proposal for a solution in which I am trying to prove that the given set of connectives is inadequate using a property that is true for every proposition that is built using this set of connectives.
Need to show that the set $\{\lnot ,G\}$ of logical connectives is inadequate where $G$ is a ternary connective that gives $T$ (True) if most of its propositions are $T$.
I noticed that the following property holds :

> For every truth assignment $v$ and for every proposition $\phi$ that is built using the given set $\{\lnot ,G\}$ we get that $v(\phi) \neq v^C(\phi)$ when $v^C$ is defined to be the opposite truth assignment

Now I tried to formalize this using structural induction but I got stuck on the inductive step, I'll appreciate any help

Comment: @Bram28 I mean that for any truth assignment of atomic propositions then the $V^C(\phi) != v(\phi)$ holds for any proposition that is built using the given connectives.

Comment: Oh, I see!  OK, then yes, that approach totally works!  I'll sketch the inductive proof pattern in an Answer momentarily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the proof that for any $v$ and $\phi$ it is true that $v^C(\phi) \neq v(\phi)$ (i.e. that $v^C(\phi)$ and $v(\phi)$ always have the opposite truth-value).

We take any $v$, and now do structural induction on $\phi$:

Base:  $\phi = P$ for some atomic proposition $P$. Given that by definition $v^C(P)$ is the opposite of $v(P)$, we have that $v^C(\phi)$ and $v(\phi)$ have the opposite truth-value as well.

Step: There are two cases to consider:

A.  $\phi = \neg \psi$, where by inductive hypothesis we have that $v^C(\psi)$ and $v(\psi)$ have the opposite truth-value. By semantics of $\neg$, we have that $v(\psi)$ and $v(\neg \psi)$ have opposite truth-values, and we also have that $v^C(\psi)$ and $v^C(\neg \psi)$ have opposite truth-values. So, $v^C(\phi) = v^C(\neg \psi)$ has the opposite value of $v^C(\psi)$. But since by inductive hypothesis $v^C(\psi)$ has the opposite value of $v(\psi)$, that means that $v^C(\phi)$ has the same truth-value as $v(\psi)$ .... but that has the opposite truth-value as $v(\phi)$.

B. $\phi = G(\psi_1, \psi_2,\psi_3)$, where by inductive hypothesis we have that $v^C(\psi_i)$ and $v(\psi_i)$ have the opposite truth-value for $1 \leq i \leq 3$. Now, $v^C(\phi)$ evaluates to True iff the majority of $v^C(\psi_i)$ evaluates to True iff (Inductive Hypothesis) the majority of $v(\psi_i)$ evaluates to False iff $v(\phi)$ evaluates to False. (in that last step, we use the fact that $G$ takes an odd number of argument, so there is always either a majority of argument that evaluate to True, or a majority of argument that evaluate to False.). So, $v^C(\phi)$ and $v(\phi)$ will have opposite truth-values.